# Show that $\lim_{r\uparrow 1}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x-y)\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{iny}\,\mathrm{d}y=f(x)$ for any $2\pi$-periodic $f$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

> Let $0<r<1$ and consider the series $$s = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty r^{|n|}e^{inx}.$$

I have already shown that this series converges (uniformly) to $$P_r(x)=\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos x+r^2}$$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Now I am asked to...

> Let $f$ be a continous $2\pi$-periodic function. Show that $$g(x)\equiv\lim_{r\uparrow 1}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x-y)P_r(y)\,\mathrm{d}y=f(x).$$

I must admit that I am not even sure how to begin. The function $g(x)$ looks to me like the limit of the convolution of $f$ with $P_r$ as $r\uparrow1$, but I am not familiar enough with convolutions to know if there are some related results which are immideately applicable to this problem.

I tried using the series representation of $P_r(x)$ and changing variables $y\rightarrow u=x-y$, but ended up with something like $$g(x)=\lim_{r\uparrow1}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty -r^{|n|}e^{inx}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{x+\pi}^{x-\pi}f(u)e^{-inu}\,\mathrm{d}u.$$ I am unsure how this helps. I notice that the integral part now looks a lot like a fourier transform, but I don't know how to use that to advance.

If any of you fine gentlemen could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the integral into
$$ \left( \int_{-\pi}^{-\delta} + \int_{\delta}^{\pi} \right) f(x-y) P_r(y) \, dy + \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} f(x-y) P_r(y) \, dy. $$
In the first integral, you can show that $P_r(y) \to 0$ uniformly, and hence that the integral tends to zero uniformly. Now use the mean value theorem for integrals on the second one, taking out the $f(x-y)$, and show that the integral
$$ \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} P_r(y) \, dy \to 2\pi\ $$
as $r \uparrow 1$ for any fixed $\delta>0$. Then take $\delta \to 0$.

(Recommendation: show that the integral over the whole circle of $P_r$ is $1$ for any, and then the uniform convergence to zero elsewhere shows the mass has to go *somewhere*, namely $[-\delta,\delta]$, by the monotone convergence theorem or somesuch.)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. This was very helpful! Although, I'm not sure where the $r\rightarrow\infty$ came from. :)

Comment: Golly, dunno how that got through... fixed.

Comment: @Chappers Nice solution, but .... $\int P_rdy  \to 2 \pi$ as $r \to 1$.     I hope that you don't mind my editing this.

Comment: @Dr.MV Ah yes, of course. Thank you.